# laravel showing error gives failed to open stream: no such file or directory autoload.php

Tags: laravel

Im new with laravel and give me error showing: failed to open stream: no such file or directory autoload.php

im using:

- windows 8
- composer
- laravel 5
- wampserver
- php 5.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're missing `vendor/autoload.php` and this is probably because when you tried to install laravel, composer threw an error about you trying to use PHP 5.3. Laravel 5 requires at least 5.4.

On a side note PHP 5.3 is end of life and unsupported.

Comment: exactly and whats my solution? how can i install laravel 4

Comment: Upgrade PHP versions to at least 5.4, ideally 5.6 as thats the current version.

An alternative would be to use Homestead. Homestead is a Vagrant virtual machine designed specifically for Laravel so everything works perfectly out of the box. http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/homestead